# Adding an organization to a channel and composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am working out the steps for how we can add a third organization to the Fabric while using Composer.

While going through the tutorial for [Deploying to a multi-organization Hyperledger Fabric](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org), you start the network and specify the network administrators with the same command:

```
composer network start -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1 -n trade-network -V 0.1.14 -o endorsementPolicyFile=/tmp/composer/endorsement-policy.json -A alice -C alice/admin-pub.pem -A bob -C bob/admin-pub.pem
```

Working through the [Adding a Org to a Channel](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/channel_update_tutorial.html) tutorial, I've added the third organization. But that tutorial does not address composer and cards (since it's dealing with Fabric, not Composer). I can easily create the appropriate cards, following the steps in the multi-organization tutorial for the new organization, but I don't see how to add the new network admins to the network. `composer network start` allows for the `--networkAdmin` and `--networkAdminCertificateFile` arguments, but `composer network upgrade` doesn't have anything similar.

So how do we add more network administrators to a network? Or perhaps a better question is what does adding the  `--networkAdmin` and `--networkAdminCertificateFile` do when running `composer network start` and I can work back from there?

I am running Composer v0.19.0 and Fabric v1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you may have already tested your new 3-Org Fabric network at a Fabric level - eg deploying the Fabric marbles https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles/tree/v4.0/chaincode/src/marbles to your altered blockchain Fabric network.

As you've seen in the tutorial, you first do a `composer network install` of the business network onto the peers (using someone with peer admin authority in that Org and using Composer connection profile that was created, similar to that shown in the tutorial link you refer to - to build the peer admin business network card in question).  Obviously you will also need to set up your endorsement policy according to how you want the policy to be implemented across 3 organisations. Again, you'll see that in the tutorial.

When the business network is started, the certificates (the public part of the identity) for all of the business network administrators must be passed to the organisation (in our example, it was Org 1)  performing the `start` command to start the business network - across the channel - which is defined in the Composer connection profile, as you'll have seen. After the business network has been started, all of the business network administrators (in their respective orgs) can use their identities to interact with the business network, via business network cards, which uses their public/private key credentials. The certs are sourced for the start bit, as this is the case for a multi-Org setup (as opposed to the Developer tutorial environment setup, where enrolment id / enrol secret was used to ).

In the Multi-Org tutorial, we're using a request command to request pre-existing identities (certificates) for alice and bob from their respective CA servers  - it uses the Fabric CA client under the covers to do that. Your new CA (Org3) can issue identities (at a Fabric level) for a business network admin, similar to 'alice' and 'bob' in the other orgs . Once you have the certificate (with the public key) you can use this with the composer network start command:

composer network start -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1 -n trade-network -V 0.1.14 -o endorsementPolicyFile=/tmp/composer/endorsement-policy.json -A alice -C alice/admin-pub.pem -A bob -C bob/admin-pub.pem -A xxx -C xxx/

and the profile used by the 'PeerAdmin' (in our case) will need to have the peer information for Org 3 in its connection.json connection profile, which is part of its business network card,

Then you can use composer card create command to create the business network card for the business network admin in Org 3 using his/her public/private key eg,

composer card create -p /tmp/composer/org3/byfn-network-org1.json -u xname -n trade-network -c xxx/xxx-pub.pem -k xxx/xxxx-priv.pem

and import it using `composer card import`

For the creation of cards - see https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/composer.card.create.html

For adding a 3rd Org to an existing business network already operational, you would need to run `composer identity bind` as an existing participant in the business network. This is the act of the existing business network  participants agreeing (via blockchain transaction) that the new business network participant can join and use its identity. So as mentioned, you need to enroll the 3rd Org's Fabric CA admin, get a certificate/private key pair for him, and then bind the certificate to the network admin in the business network. Once bound, it can interact with the business network, and since it would be Fabric CA admin, it can be used to issue new identities in that Org.

Comment: Thank you.  I also opened a [ticket on GitHub](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3858#issuecomment-389426690) a few days after I started this, and before you responded.

I've added the steps I needed to do there. What you said in your last paragraph was what I was looking for.

Comment: Hi @Paul O'Mahony can you elaborate the last paragraph more . An example or so .. Thanks